# Create a Binding whose only variables are keys from a Hash

Tags: ruby

I know I can create a Binding from a Hash using `ostruct`, like this:

```
require 'ostruct'

not_in_locals = "we don't want this"
locals = {a: 1, b: 2}
my_binding = OpenStruct.new(locals).instance_eval { binding }
p my_binding
p eval("a", my_binding) #good, we want this
p eval("b", my_binding) #good, we want this
p eval("not_in_locals", my_binding) #bad, don't want it to access this, but it can
```

You can see the output here, which confirms the comments in the code: https://eval.in/132925

As you can see, the problem is that the Binding also binds variables in the local context that are *not* in the Hash.  I'd like a method for creating Binding objects from a Hash, which are bound to nothing besides the keys from that Hash.

Comment: what output do you expect of, let's say, `eval ('true', my_binding)`?

Comment: well "true" would be "true" in any binding, right?  that's what i'd expect anyway.  here's a really ugly, but working solution to my OP: https://eval.in/132941 (not that `__string__` is bound too so it's not an exact solution)

Comment: Well, if you wanted a completely "clean" binding (nothing defined at all except for your hash data), it should return `nil`. `true` if you are ok with the binding carrying all its environment with it.

Comment: hmmm... interesting.  but isn't "true" just a language keyword, rather than lvar with a value?  fwiw, as a practical matter a solution that was not clean in this sense (true = true) would be fine for me.

Comment: `true` is not a keyword, it's just a global value (unique instance of `TrueClass`). Anyway, I was referring to anything you can normally access, global values, methods of `Object`, `Kernel`, the list is pretty long in Ruby. BTW, it's a good question, unfortunately I don't know the answer :)

Comment: Well this is the best I've come up with it, still convoluted for my taste: https://eval.in/132948

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.  It bypasses a straight eval() call for a helper class method call.  The helper class method is called evaluate(), but it only works for very simple values (only Strings and Integers tested so far) and relies on inspect().

But if the types of the values you are dealing with is known ahead of time, you could modify this to work.

```rb
class HashBinding
  def initialize(hash)
    @hash = hash
  end

  def evaluate(str)
    binding_code = @hash.to_a.map do |k,v|
      "#{k} = #{v.inspect};"
    end.join(" ")
    eval "#{binding_code}; #{str}"
  end
end

not_in_hash = 'I am not in the hash'
hash = { :foo => 'foo value', :baz => 42}
hash_binding = HashBinding.new(hash)

hash_binding.evaluate('puts "foo = #{foo}"')
hash_binding.evaluate('puts "baz = #{baz}"')
hash_binding.evaluate('puts "not_in_hash = #{not_in_hash}"')
```

The output is:

```
ruby binding_of_hash.rb
foo = foo value
baz = 42
binding_of_hash.rb:10:in `eval': undefined local variable or method `not_in_hash' for #<HashBinding:0x007fcc0b9ec1e8> (NameError)
    from binding_of_hash.rb:10:in `eval'
    from binding_of_hash.rb:10:in `evaluate'
    from binding_of_hash.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

Comment: upvoting because i appreciate the answer and it *does* solve the problem, but, well, you have to admit that's quite a hack.

Comment: Never claimed it wasn't a hack ;)

Comment: More than hackish, using `inspect` just doesn't work in general, try to run this code: `HashBinding.new(foo: Object.new).evaluate('puts "foo = #{foo}"')`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another "less" hacky try that doesn't rely on "inspect" serialization.

```rb
require 'json'

class HashBinding
  attr_accessor :hash
  def initialize(hash)
    # Require symbol keys
    @hash = Hash[hash.map {|k,v| [k.to_sym, v]}]
  end

  def evaluate(str)
    binding_code = @hash.to_a.map do |k,v|
      "#{k} = @hash[:#{k}];"
    end.join(" ")
    eval "#{binding_code}; #{str}"
  end
end

not_in_hash = 'I am not in the hash'
hash = { :foo => 'foo value', :baz => 42, 'str' => "a string value"}
hash_binding = HashBinding.new(hash)

hash_binding.evaluate('puts "foo = #{foo}"')
hash_binding.evaluate('puts "baz = #{baz}"')
hash_binding.evaluate('puts "str = #{str}"')
hash_binding.evaluate('puts "not_in_hash = #{not_in_hash}"')
```

Comment: The problem is this is still more complex than the solution I posted in my last comment in the OP, which is itself too complex I think.  I actually think the answer is that there just isn't a good answer, unfortunately.